# virtual list control scrolling is painfully slow

Tags: mfc, listcontrol, virtuallistview

I subclassed from CMFCListControl and create a list control in Report View (LVS_REPORT) to display data.  As my data contains a million records, populating the list control was slow AF upfront (6 minutes on average), but very fluid after.  I switched to the virtual list control using the LVS_OWNERDATA window style.  It works BETTER (75 seconds in debug), HOWEVER, after the initial display, ANY attempt to scroll is painfully slow.  It works, and never crashes, but it takes 2 minute to display the change.  The data read is in a std::map in memory, so disk drives or network latency issues are not the cause.

```cpp
void CAlbumListCtrl::OnLvnGetdispinfo(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    NMLVDISPINFO *pDispInfo = reinterpret_cast<NMLVDISPINFO*>(pNMHDR);
    LVITEM &Item = (pDispInfo)->item;
    CString csTemp;
    
    ASSERT(m_pLibrary);
    if (!m_pLibrary)
        AfxThrowMemoryException();
    
    const CImageEntry *pEntry = m_pLibrary->GetImageEntryAt((size_t)Item.iItem);
    //pListCtrl->SetItemText(nCount, 1, pEntry->GetItemName().c_str());
    //pListCtrl->SetItemText(nCount, 2, pEntry->GetPathName().c_str());
    //pListCtrl->SetItemText(nCount, 3, pLib->GetImageEntryType(pEntry).c_str());
    
    if (Item.mask & LVIF_TEXT) //valid text buffer?
    {
        switch (Item.iSubItem)
        {
        case 0: //fill in ID
            //_tcscpy_s(Item.pszText, Item.cchTextMax,
            //  m_Items[iItem].m_strItemText);
            csTemp.Format(_T("%ld"), pEntry->GetItemId());
            _tcscpy_s(Item.pszText, Item.cchTextMax, csTemp);
            break;
        case 1: //fill in sub item 1 text
            _tcscpy_s(Item.pszText, Item.cchTextMax, pEntry->GetItemName().c_str());
            break;
        case 2: //fill in sub item 2 text
            _tcscpy_s(Item.pszText, Item.cchTextMax, pEntry->GetPathName().c_str());
            break;
        case 3: //fill in sub item 1 text
            _tcscpy_s(Item.pszText, Item.cchTextMax, m_pLibrary->GetImageEntryType(pEntry).c_str());
            break;
        //case 2: //fill in sub item 2 text
            //  _tcscpy_s(Item.pszText, Item.cchTextMax, pEntry->GetPathName().c_str());
            //  break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

```cpp
int CAlbumView::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;
    
    m_wndTabCtrl.Create(TCS_TABS | TCS_FIXEDWIDTH | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
            CRect(0, 0, 20, 20), this, IDC_ALBUMVIEW_HEADERTAB);
    
    if (!m_wndTabCtrl.m_hWnd)
        return -1;
    
    m_wndTabCtrl.InsertItem(0, _T("List View"));
    m_wndTabCtrl.InsertItem(1, _T("Tree View"));
    
    m_listCtrl.Create(LVS_REPORT | LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS | LVS_OWNERDATA | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(0, 0, 20, 20), this, IDC_LISTCTRL);
    m_listCtrl.SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT | LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER | LVS_EX_ONECLICKACTIVATE);
    m_listCtrl.InsertColumn(0, _T("ID"), LVCFMT_CENTER, 150);
    m_listCtrl.InsertColumn(1, _T("Nickname"), LVCFMT_CENTER, 100);
    m_listCtrl.InsertColumn(2, _T("Image File Pathname"), LVCFMT_CENTER, 500);
    m_listCtrl.InsertColumn(3, _T("Image Type"), LVCFMT_CENTER, 100);
    m_listCtrl.InsertColumn(4, _T("Dimensions"), LVCFMT_CENTER, 75);
    m_listCtrl.InsertColumn(5, _T("Color Depth"), LVCFMT_CENTER, 95);
    m_listCtrl.InsertColumn(6, _T("Tags"), LVCFMT_CENTER, 150);
        
    m_treeCtrl.Create(TVS_HASBUTTONS | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(0, 0, 20, 20), this, IDC_TREECTRL);
    
    SetVisibleViewCtrl(0);
    
    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
void CAlbumView::UpdateView()
{
    std::map<wstring, vector<wstring>> mapImageFilesByFolder;
    time_t start = time(NULL);
    auto *pFrame = GetParentFrame();
    size_t nCount = 0;
    if (pFrame)
    {
        CImageLibrary *pLib = pFrame->GetImageLibrary();
        CAlbumView *pView = pFrame->GetAlbumView();
        CAlbumListCtrl *pListCtrl = pView->GetListCtrl();
        CAlbumTreeCtrl *pTreeCtrl = pView->GetTreeCtrl();
        CUpdatingViewDlg dlg;
        dlg.Create(this);
        dlg.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
        dlg.CenterWindow();
        dlg.RedrawWindow();
        pListCtrl->SendMessage(WM_SETREDRAW, FALSE);
        pTreeCtrl->SendMessage(WM_SETREDRAW, FALSE);
        nCount = pLib->GetImageCount();
        pListCtrl->SetItemCountEx((int)nCount);
        pListCtrl->SetImageLibrary(pLib);
        SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), 7);
        POSITION pos = pLib->EnumImageEntries();
        if (::IsWindow(pListCtrl->m_hWnd))
        {
            pListCtrl->DeleteAllItems();
            pTreeCtrl->DeleteAllItems();
            int nCount = 0;
            while (pos != (POSITION)-1)
            {
                CString csTemp;
                const CImageEntry *pEntry = pLib->GetCurrentImageEntry(pos);
                csTemp.Format(_T("%ld"), pEntry->GetItemId());
                pListCtrl->InsertItem(nCount, csTemp);
                //pListCtrl->SetItemText(nCount, 1, pEntry->GetItemName().c_str());
                //pListCtrl->SetItemText(nCount, 2, pEntry->GetPathName().c_str());
                //pListCtrl->SetItemText(nCount, 3, pLib->GetImageEntryType(pEntry).c_str());
                //pTreeCtrl->ParseAndAddFile(pEntry->GetPathName().c_str());
                pos = pLib->GetNextPos(pos);
                ++nCount;
            }
    
            CString csTemp;
            csTemp.Format(_T("Done in %d seconds."), time(NULL) - start);
            MessageBox(csTemp, _T("X"));
    
            SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), 0);
            pListCtrl->SendMessage(WM_SETREDRAW, TRUE);
            pListCtrl->RedrawWindow(NULL, NULL, RDW_ERASE | RDW_FRAME | RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_ALLCHILDREN);
            pTreeCtrl->SendMessage(WM_SETREDRAW, TRUE);
            pTreeCtrl->RedrawWindow(NULL, NULL, RDW_ERASE | RDW_FRAME | RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_ALLCHILDREN);
            dlg.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
            dlg.DestroyWindow();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a profiler to see where the time is sunk. A poor-man's profiler is to hit the Break button repeatedly and see in the debugger where the  program stopped. If It's always in the same function, you know where you have to look further.

Comment: In Virtual mode you should not populate list at all. And without the actual code shown no one can tell you where exactly your problem lays down.

Comment: You shouldn't call `InsertItem()` for a virtual list-control, you should just call `SetItemCount()`. That's the whole point of virtual list-controls, ie not maintaining the data themselves. Instead you need to respond to the `LVN_GETDISPINFO` message (which you do) as efficiently as possible: given the item index and subitem index  you must return the information requested from the data you maintain yourself - use an efficient access mechanism, for example arrays and vectors are traditionally considered more efficient than lists.

Comment: If `GetPathName()` returns a string reference that out-lives  `OnLvnGetdispinfo()`, then you do not have to copy the `.c_str()` result, but you can just assign it to `.pszText` (after a `const_cast`).

Comment: Please see the documentation on the [Virtual List-View Style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-controls-overview#virtual-list-view-style).

Comment: @Constantine Georgiou, but when I just call SetItemCountEx, NOTHING displays

Comment: Can't you put the code that fills up the list in a background thread?

Answer (score 3):

So you create a `LVS_OWNERDATA` (virtual) list-view control and set its style to `LVS_REPORT`. Btw, isn't a rectangle of (0,0,20,20) too small? But I see you are using the same coordinates for other controls as well, so I guess you re-arrange them later (code not shown here).

The function processing the `LVN_GETDISPINFO` notification must be declared in your class's message-map, to associate the function to the message:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAlbumView, ...)
    .
    .
    ON_NOTIFY(LVN_GETDISPINFO, IDC_LISTCTRL, &CAlbumView::OnLvnGetdispinfoListCtlr)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

This is what wizard-generated code would look like, if you didn't subclass from `CMFCListControl` and instead simply used `CMFCListControl` as is. But you create the control yourself, so please disregard this remark if you have correctly made the aforementioned declaration in the child class's message-map and you found that the function is actually called (debug or trace).

I think the reason why your code doesn't work is because you copy the items' texts to a buffer supposedly pointed by the `pszText` instead of setting the `pszText` pointer. Here is a excerpt from the documentation about the **[LV_ITEM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-lvitema)** structure:

`pszText`
*If the structure specifies item attributes, pszText is a pointer to a null-terminated string containing the item text. When responding to an LVN_GETDISPINFO notification, be sure that this pointer remains valid until after the next notification has been received.*

Also:
`cchTextMax`
*This member is only used when the structure receives item attributes. ... It is read-only during LVN_GETDISPINFO and other LVN_ notifications.*

And the example in the **[LVN_GETDISPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvn-getdispinfo)** documentation does exactly this.

So, your code could be changed as shown below:

```cpp
    void CAlbumListCtrl::OnLvnGetdispinfo(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
    {
        NMLVDISPINFO *pDispInfo = reinterpret_cast<NMLVDISPINFO*>(pNMHDR);
        LVITEM &Item = (pDispInfo)->item;
        CString csTemp;
        static TCHAR _szItemId[20]; // Persistent buffer
        
        ASSERT(m_pLibrary);
        if (!m_pLibrary)
            AfxThrowMemoryException();
        
        const CImageEntry *pEntry = m_pLibrary->GetImageEntryAt((size_t)Item.iItem);
        
        if (Item.mask & LVIF_TEXT) //Item/subItem text
        {
            switch (Item.iSubItem)
            {
            case 0: //fill in ID
                csTemp.Format(_T("%ld"), pEntry->GetItemId());
                 _tcscpy_s(_szItemId, csTemp);
                Item.pszText = _szItemId;
                break;
            case 1: //fill in sub item 1 text
                Item.pszText = pEntry->GetItemName().c_str();
                break;
            case 2: //fill in sub item 2 text
                Item.pszText = pEntry->GetPathName().c_str();
                break;
            case 3: //fill in sub item 3 text
                Item.pszText = m_pLibrary->GetImageEntryType(pEntry).c_str();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        
        *pResult = 0;
    }
```

**Notes:**

- I only modified this code in a text editor, it's not actually tested. It may need some minor fixes to even compile.
- The `InsertItem()` and `DeleteAllItems()` calls (along with that browsing of the list) must be removed, as the control does not really store any content, instead it requests the data of the items being displayed, through the LVN_GETDISPINFO message (referenced by the item's index - `iItem`).

Comment: you ROCK!  Ok, so yes, in OnSize, I set the list control to be the size of the window client area, minus the height of the tab control (about 25 pixels).

Comment: For everyone else, the issue was the Item retrieval, as I was traversing an std::map like an std::vector, using for(auto itor = begin(); itor != end(); ++itor).  That was the bottleneck for a million records.  I took your suggestions, and give the slowness of the map iteration, encapsulated my data into a separate class using an interface of methods.  I have a vector, and two maps so I can find an entry by index, by image path, and by id.  Virtual list control works like a charm now.  I cannot thank you all enough!